# Colour of pixel is wrong only for iPhone 6 simulator

Tags: ios, swift, pixel, rgba, iphone-6

I need to read a colour of a pixel located at a point in an image and the code I have works in simulator for all iPhones (including iPhone 6 Plus) except iPhone 6.

I do not know why, but my guess is the index of the pixel is not correct since it detects a colour in a wrong location.
I appreciate any help.
This is the code that I have.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(upperCaseView.frame.size)
upperCaseView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(snapshotImage.CGImage))
let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

let pixelInfo: Int = ((Int(snapshotImage.size.width) * Int(point.y)) + Int(point.x)) * 4

print(data[pixelInfo])
print(data[pixelInfo+1])
print(data[pixelInfo+2])
```

Comment: Provide the `point.y` and `point.x` values for the working and non-working devices.

Comment: Are you certain that your image data is encoded in the proper pixel format on all platforms?  Are you defining the image format yourself, or are you relying on the operating system to pick one for you?  In general you shouldn't be relying on the width of the image to tell you how many bytes are in each row as image data sometimes includes instead use CGImageGetBytesPerRow.

Comment: the image is a snapshot of the whole screen (I added the code in my post)

Comment: For all simulators except iPhone 6, it works for any point on the screen. For iPhone 6 simulator, it seems it is not working

Comment: I used CGImageGetBytesPerRow instead of the image width, it works now, thank you so much for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Scott Thompson.

I used CGImageGetBytesPerRow instead of the image width and now it works.
The correct code is below:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(upperCaseView.frame.size)
    upperCaseView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    let pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(snapshotImage.CGImage))
    let data: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)

    let bytesPerPixel = (CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(snapshotImage.CGImage) / 8)
    let bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(snapshotImage.CGImage)
    let pixelInfo: Int = (bytesPerRow * Int(point.y)) + (Int(point.x) * bytesPerPixel)

    print(data[pixelInfo])
    print(data[pixelInfo+1])
    print(data[pixelInfo+2])
```